# Adding data to a treeview table as it is generated

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I need somebody to guide me in Tkinter, I have built a desktop app that generates random phone numbers and now I wish to add those numbers to a treeview table, Can somebody guide me how to automatically add those numbers to the table as they are generated. If somebody could give me a code for it that would be nice

Comment: Have you looked at `.after` scripts? Also do you want the new data to be added every x seconds or when a button is clicked or when the user presses a key?

Comment: Post what have you tried so far and state what is the problem you come across.